# Shortcut to set all the fields in serializers to 'required=False'?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

sorry if its duplicate, but I am not able to find the solution.

Is there any way to set all the fields in serializers as required=False in one line, rather than declaring each field and explicitly write required=False for each field ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ...

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ("foo", "bar",)
        extra_kwargs = {field: {'required': False} for field in fields}
```